# Changing Preference title text color the correct way

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want a text of a title of a preference to change its color to white when another preference (a `SwitchPreference`) is changed. When the other preference is changed I'm invoking this method from the `onPreferenceChange` listener:

```
private void enableSettingsGui(boolean enable)
{
    View preferenceView = getListView().getChildAt(myPref.getOrder());
    TextView title = (TextView)preferenceView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```

Now there are 2 scenarios:

1) If I'm returning true in the `onPreferenceChange` method, the switch of the `SwitchPreference` is changed correctly (meaning sliding left or right as to its new state of enabled or disabled), but the color of the title of the affected preference is not changed.

2)If I'm returning false from the `onPreferenceChange`, the switch does not change, however the title text color suddenly does change.

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem.

According the documentation regarding `onPreferenceChange`, the return value is

> "True to update the state of the Preference with the new value. "

That means that the switch changed because the return value told him to update the state. The color seemed like it did not set, but it actually did, just that in order to change the state, the `onCreate` method of the preference was called again, thus overriding the color change.

What I did was to override the `setEnabled` method like this:

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled)
{
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    shouldEnable = enabled;
}
```

And then in `onCreate` added the line: `setTitleTextColor(shouldEnable);` which color the text according to the enabled state. This way the changes were made AFTER the view was recreated and the color remained.